# Magento Google Analytics Content Experiments

Tags: magento, testing, google-analytics, google-experiments

What is the simplest way to implement `Google Analytics Content Experiment` into `Magento CE`?

I want to test home page content.

Adding the `Testing Code` to `CMS` pages does not work. Testing Tag is after Analytics Tag.

Does Magento support adding the `Testing Tag` via admin Interface?
Or is there a simple way to add the tag via `XML Layout Update`?

Would it be possible to use `Google Tag Manager` to add the codes we need?

Answer (score 0):

Tags could be installed after body like:

Add to local.xml in your layout folder following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
Last loaded layout file
-->
<layout>
  <default>
    <reference name="after_body_start">
      <block type="cms/block" name="tags-first-in-body" before="-">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>tags-first-in-body</block_id></action>
      </block>
    </reference>
  </default>
</layout>
```

and add a static block called tags-first-in-body.
Insert code to this block.